# What do I need to provide to enter dkim, spf & sender id for server? I am trying to send emails through a server

Tags: email, smtp

I am trying to send out a mass email through a server. I need to know what to provide I enter for dkim, spf, and sender id in order to get these emails out through our server.

Answer (score 1):

In order to send your email through the server, you have to do few things.

Before anything else, you have to worry about your IP being a static IP instead of a dynamic IP. If you have a dynamic IP, most servers will reject your mail.

The second thing you have to worry about is a reverse DNS. Now, you have to have a reverse DNS for your IP, so your IP should reverse DNS lookup to your domain. Now that you have that taken care of, the other things you have to worry about are DKIM, SPF, and Sender ID. Now, the Sender ID and SPF are solely focused on your DNS server- they have nothing to do with your email server at all. DKIM has to do with both, so you need to set up one part in your mail server and another to your DNS.

So, for SPF, what you can do is there's a lot of SPF generators, so to speak, and you can look it up on the Internet and find "SPF Generator". Now, with that generator, you specify which IP addresses and which DNS addresses you have to allow
access from and it will generate a string that you will need to put into your DNS record.
With Sender ID, it's pretty similar and you can find it, but Sender ID is not being widely used so much- I would even skip it if you don't really need it for something very specific.
DKIM as well, it's pretty optional. You have DKIM generators and you need to generate a pair of keys - but it's very specific for the server you are using.